# Why my css and images can not be read by maven

Tags: css, image, maven

I have a maven project and I want to use a css on the project but it only shows the index.jsp page and no any images and css.
What can it depends on?

I put my css and images under resources and here is my servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

</beans:beans>
```

please any help?

Comment: as simple as this may be, check all your spelling. If you miss something simple it won't display your images or apply the css to the page

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with the spelling any where. Or what I can see.

Comment: How are you accessing the CSS/JS in your JSP, etc.? Where are those files located in your project (should be under `webapp` by default)? We'll need details to diagnose.

Comment: I have them under resources and not webapp.

Comment: And accessing the css  in index.jsp by:                                                                                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="                                       <%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/stylesheet.css"/>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This doesn't sound like a Maven issue to me.  I think you may have confused the Spring example   resources mapping with the standard Maven resources folder.  In this case, your images should be relative to the src/main/webapp folder (i.e. src/main/webapp/resources not src/main/resources).  Maven itself doesn't do anything special with src/main/webapp/resources folder.

Update

Just to be clear, the folder "resources" under webapp could be named anything.  To reduce any confusion, I've renamed mine to "webstuff".  As an example, I have

```
src/main/webapp/webstuff
src/main/webapp/webstuff/css/base.css
src/main/webapp/webstuff/images/globe.png
```

Now, in my Spring config, I've changed it to look like this:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/webstuff/**" location="/webstuff/" />
```

The final piece is in how I reference the css & image in my jsp:

```
<html>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="webstuff/css/default.css" type="text/css">
    <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <img src="webstuff/images/globe.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks i created the resources file in the webapp and now I get the css but not all images and therefore the index.jsp is not completely working. Don't know what it can depends on but thanks

Comment: I added      : <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/images/**"              location="/r esources/images/" />  to the servlet-context.xml  to get the images but didn't work any suggestion?

Comment: You shouldn't need the extra mapping for images, the /resources/** indicates any files or folders under the resources folder.  When you said not all of the images are working does that mean that some of them are working?  If so, I'd carefully check the paths and names specified in your .jsp in case of a typing error.

Comment: No I removed the lines too but still the same problem and I checked the path to the images and write            <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/stylesheet.css" />                               to find the correct path to the images but nix no any help and spelling and anything else is correct too.

Comment: I added an update to add an example.  You should be able to leave the getContextPath out, but if not, do a View Source in the browser and look at the path that it resolves to.  Verify that it looks correct and attempt to access the resource directly.

Comment: @ShawnSherwood By using default war plugin configuration, any file under resource folder falls under WEB-INF\classes right? Then changing the resource mapping wont help. He need to look into the war file to see how the jsp'g got bundled. Using that we can give him a solution.

Comment: Check out his view resolver. Even it is mapped to WEB-INF/views. But he have the pages in some other location. (what I assume is WEB-INF/classes/)

Comment: @om39a Yes, Maven puts the files from src/main/resources into the WEB-INF/classes folder, but I believe the specific request was around css and image files.  In a typical Maven web project you would never put your css and image files in the /src/main/resources folder (typically you might have log4j or other config files there).  If the problem really is with images, then the view resolver is probably working fine and the confusion was around the Spring config that used the folder name "resources".  We'll need a little more info from user1067665 before we can be sure.

Comment: Hi everyone it's suddenly working now. Don't know how and why but after cleaning the eclipse 2-5 times and wow it's working thanks for all help and suggestion thanks everyone and thanks for spending your times to answer my question, very grateful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have  you created the project as a dynamic web application in eclipse or did you use maven archetypes and then imported the project to eclipse? Because, I was facing the same problem few days back. This is because the folder structure that you have is not mapped correctly in your web app. What I would suggest you to do it, try to extract the war from the target folder and check if the files (jsp, htlm and java) are in the correct location ass you have mentioned in the servlet-context. If it is correct in the war, then it should work fine. If some files are misplaced then you will face a problem.

You can configure the path where the files should do in the .war by using maven's war plugin. Check out [this](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) for more.

Follow [this](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/generate-dynamic-web-project-maven-eclipse-wtp/) tutorial to see who to create a web project (applies for spring too) and try it out.

Comment: Created by: mvn archetype:generate .It is correct and the problem is even the colors on the jsp side are not correct colors and only one picture is shown. And  I have checked everything and even spelling and it's ok.

Comment: Extract the war file and check for the file paths. Because, the path after deployment will be different than the one in the workspace. I think that is the problem that you are facing.